# Calculus: Find the Limit of (f(x+h)-f(x))/h as h approaches 0 for f(x)=cos(2x)

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Find the limit:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Given that $f(x) = \cos(2x)$

Tried many ways, but I kept on getting an indeterminate form. I can't find a way to cancel out terms on the numerator and denominator.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The OP posted a comment below nbubis's answer asking what to do with $\frac{\sin^2(\frac{h}{2})}{h}$. I can't comment back, (no reputation at all) so here's my contribution, multiply $\frac{h}{4}$  in the numerator and denominator. This will lead to $\frac{\sin^2(\frac{h}{2})}{(\frac{h}{2})^2}*\frac{h}{4}$. The first term is just one squared, the second term is $0$. So the term evaluates to zero. Accept his answer.

**EDIT**: I decided to post my own version of the answer anyway.

We know that, $\cos(C)-\cos(D)=2\sin(\frac{C+D}{2})\sin(\frac{D-C}{2})$

Now, Let $C=2x+h, D=2x$

Hence, our limit becomes, $\frac{2\sin(\frac{4x+h}{2})sin(\frac{-h}{2})}{\frac{h}{2}}$

Now, $\frac{\sin(\frac{-h}{2})}{h}$ evaluates to $-\frac{1}{2}$. Proceed.

Comment: I'd +1 his answer if I could, but again rep. :p

Comment: I finally got it, thank you so much!

Comment: You will always get help on [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos (2x+2h)-\cos 2x}{h}
$$
But
$$
\begin{align*}
\cos (2x+2h)-\cos 2x&=\cos 2x\cos 2h-\sin 2x\sin 2h-\cos2x\\
&=(\cos 2x\cos2h-\cos2x)-\sin2x\sin2h\\
&=\cos2x(\cos2h-1)-\sin2x\sin2h\\
&=\cos2x(1-2\sin^2h-1)-\sin2x\sin2h\\
&=-2\cos2x\sin^2h-\sin2x\sin2h
\end{align*}
$$
Thus the above limit can be written as
$$
-2\cos2x\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{\sin h}{h}\sin h\right)-\sin2x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin2h}{h}
$$
Using the following limit
$$
\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac{\sin\alpha}{\alpha}=1
$$
we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{\sin h}{h}\sin h\right)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin h}{h}\times\lim_{h\to0}\sin h\\
&=1\times0\\
&=0
\end{align*}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin2h}{h}&=2\lim_{2h\to0}\frac{\sin2h}{2h}\\
&=2
\end{align*}
$$
Hence
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos (2x+2h)-\cos 2x}{h}=-2\sin2x
$$

Answer (score 1):

As an additional way, you can use the chain rule.
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(2x+2h)-\cos(2x)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{(2x+2h)-2x}{(2x+2h)-2x}\frac{\cos(2x+2h)-\cos(2x)}{h}=\\\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(2x+2h)-\cos(2x)}{(2x+2h)-2x}\frac{(2x+2h)-2x}{h}$$Let u = 2x and g = 2h $$=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos(u+g)-\cos(u)}{g}\cdot2 = \lim\limits_{g\to 0}\frac{\cos(u+g)-\cos(u)}{g}\cdot2 = \\2\lim\limits_{g\to 0}\frac{\cos u\cos g - \sin u \sin g -\cos u}{g} = 2\left (\lim\limits_{g\to 0}\frac{\cos u(\cos g - 1)}{g} - \sin u \right) = 2\left (\lim\limits_{g\to 0}\cos u\frac{\cos^2 g - 1}{g(\cos g + 1)} - \sin u \right)= 2\left (\lim\limits_{g\to 0}\cos u\frac{\sin g}{\cos g + 1} - \sin u \right)=-2\sin u = -2 \sin(2x)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\cos(2x)\cos(h)-\sin(2x)\sin(h)-\cos(2x)$$
$$=\cos(2x)(1-\cos h)-\sin(2x)\sin(h)$$
$$=2\cos(2x)\sin^2(h/2)-\sin(2x)\sin(h)$$

Now use what you know about the limit $\sin (h)/h$.

Comment: I know sin(h)/h will become 1. But what can I do about
(sin^2(h/2) )/h?

Comment: We are not allowed to use L'hopital's rule

Comment: @ShaikatHaque - $\sin(h/2)/h$ is like writing $2\sin(x)/x$ do you see why? Now you have an extra $\sin(h)$ which just goes to zero.

Comment: It's clear now, thank you for your help!

Comment: @nbubis wouldn't it be 1/2 sin x/x?